# Is there a way to filter a pivot query to remove the blank column

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I would like to filter it only to show positive, neutral and negative columns and eliminate the blank column

My query:

```
={query(SMedia_Data!A1:P, "select L, count(K) where B= '"&$B1&"' and A=date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by L pivot H",1),query(SMedia_Data!A1:P, "select count(H) where B= '"&$B1&"' and A=date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by L label count(H) 'Total'")}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY(SMedia_Data!A1:P, 
 "select L,count(K) 
  where B='"&$B1&"' 
    and A=date '"&TEXT(C1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  group by L pivot H", 1), 
 QUERY(SMedia_Data!A1:P, 
 "select count(H) 
  where B='"&$B1&"' 
    and A=date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  group by L 
  label count(H)'Total'", 0)}), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```